# dotnet blazor maui UAE PASS authentication unable to redirect to the mobile app after authentication is done

Tags: c#, maui, maui-blazor, maui-android, maui-ios

I'm Developing the app with UAE pass authentication using Maui Blazor technology(C#).
successfully obtained the authorization code from UAE Pass but i am facing difficulties redirecting back to  mobile app.
Please find the attached file.
[image: Redirection issue.]
I have configured Intent filter properly in MainActivity.cs

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
Categories = new[]
{
    Intent.ActionView,
    Intent.CategoryDefault,
    Intent.CategoryBrowsable,
},
DataScheme = "https", DataHost = "patientmobile", DataPathPrefix = "/")]
```

this is the android manifest code.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:scheme="https"
            android:host="patientmobile"
            android:pathPrefix="/" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This my redirect URL:

```
https://patientmobile/?code=c8***8eb-c**9-35b9-XXX-c5ab***b629&state=XXX
```